# How to change the background color of bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a theme and there I got this weird sort of problem which I'm here sharing for solution, I want to change the `bootstrap navbar` color from `default` to `#0288D1` but even though I have mentioned this hex-code in `background-color` property of `navbar` class I haven't got the desired result.

Here is the HTML Code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
margin-bottom: 0;
background-color: #0288D1;
z-index: 9999;
border: 0;
font-size: 12px !important;
line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
letter-spacing: 4px;
border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
color: #0288D1 !important;
background-color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
border-color: transparent;
color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: your code works fine! what is your issue? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/h53phLsj/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace it with w/e color you want.It works fine to me , I dont experience any problems? Even with hex-code color;

```
.navbar{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: yeah it's working on fiddle but not on my website.. I don't know what the hell is happening! is there anyway to provide snap of my problem?

Comment: @BhavikBamania can you upload your project on github , and i`ll just clone it , and see how it works on my browser, thanks :)

Comment: hey! I got rid of this.. thanks for support actually I've messed the actually bootstrap library file code that's why I was not able to see changes! :D

Comment: @BhavikBamania damn you boy.. look closer! Okay good job that you've solved the issue by yourself! Have a good night and best of luck :)

Comment: @BhavikBamania make my answer as checked , just to be sure that that theme is answered correctly.